# print every third value from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict file that looks like this:

```
my_dict={0: 'XYZ', 1: 'XYZ', 2: 'XYZ', 3: 'XYZ', 4: 'XYZ', 5: 'XYZ', 6: 'XYZ', 7: 'XYZ', 8: 'XYZ', 9: 'XYZ', 10:'XYZ',11:'XYZ',12:'XYZ',13:'XYZ',14:'XYZ'}
```

I am trying to print every third key from the dict and also print the accompanying value.

So my desire output would look like this:

```
0-2 XYZ
3-5 XYZ
6-8 XYZ
9-11 XYZ
12-14 XYZ
```

I have tried to using the below code:

```
my_dict={0: 'XYZ', 1: 'XYZ', 2: 'XYZ', 3: 'XYZ', 4: 'XYZ', 5: 'XYZ', 6: 'XYZ', 7: 'XYZ', 8: 'XYZ', 9: 'XYZ', 10:'XYZ',11:'XYZ',12:'XYZ',13:'XYZ',14:'XYZ'}

for key, val in my_dict.iteritems():
  dash="-"
  print key,dash,value
```

Is it possible to achieve this from a dictionary or do i need to convert to a list, apprecite any suggestion.

Comment: Dicts aren't ordered. Why aren't you using a list in the first place, if you're indexing them with sequential numbers?

Comment: You could use `OrderedDict` to get a dict with order.

Comment: Where is your code grouping by 3 elements?

Comment: Get all the keys from the dict with `dict.keys()`. Sort this, then loop over it in groups of 3.

Comment: Are you sure that (a) the keys are consecutive, ie no gaps (b) the number of keys is a multiple of 3, and (c) each group of three keys has the same value, ie `my_dict[3*k] == my_dict[3*k+1] == my_dict[3*k+2]` for all integer k?

Comment: Just make a list and slice it .. `list[::3]` . Any particular reason you need to do this on a dict?

Comment: i suppose a list is the way to go, Hugh Bothwell, yes

Comment: @Barmar Dictionaries are ordered in Python 3.6

Comment: @iffy: strictly speaking, that is a Cython implementation detail (not guaranteed in other implementations) - it also works for me though (Anaconda 3.5.3).

Comment: It's not guaranteed to remain so in CPython 3.7 or later either. Writing code that relies on this is dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution could be like so:

```
my_list = [(value, s) for value, s in my_dict.iteritems()]
sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key= lambda tup: tup[0])

for index, value in sorted_list[2::3]:
    out_string = '{}-{} {}'.format(index-2, index, value)

    print out_string
```

Comment: i like this approach, easier for me to understand even though its more lines of code. one question what would happen if the dict. gets the 15th value? say from 0 ~ 15

Comment: The 15th key is already in the dict. It's `14: 'XYZ'` if you mean the 16th key, then it would not print anything cause this is not among every 3rd key of the dict.

Comment: "trying to print every third key from the dict" - This is what you asked to do :)

Comment: yes, i didnt realize that i would not get access to the rest of the values when i sliced a list that looked like this :)

`[(0, 'XYZ'), (1, 'XYZ'), (2, 'XYZ'), (3, 'XYZ'), (4, 'XYZ'), (5, 'XYZ'), (6, 'XYZ'), (7, 'XYZ')]`

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
for i in range(0, len(my_dict), 3):
    print("{}-{} {}".format(i, i+2, my_dict[i]))
```

but it depends on the contents of `my_dict` actually being as described!

Comment: i am wondering what will happen if the dict starts not from zero but say like 10

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

First I'd convert the dict into a list:

```
my_list = [(value, s) for value, s in my_dict.iteritems()]
sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key= lambda tup: tup[0])

shifted = sorted_list[2:]

# every 3rd
small_value = shorted_list[::3]
large_value = shifted[::3]

zip_values = zip(small_value, large_value)

outputs = [('{minv}-{maxv}'.format(minv=left_tup[0], maxv=right_tup[0]), right_tup[1]) for left_tup, right_tup in zip_values]
```

finally:

```
for value, key in output:
    print value, key
```